# OSGB Coordinates not showing correctly in QGIS 2.14

Tags: coordinates, qgis-2.14

The coordinate box at the foot of my map project is not showing correctly for OSGB1936 British National Grid EPSG 27700 in QGIS 2.14. This was working perfectly before I upgraded. Screen shot attached showing how they are represented. Does anyone know how to fix this?[image]

Comment: look like your map is really in lat/lon but you have told QGIS it is OSGB

Comment: In the Project properties, General tab you can select between degree coordinates and projected coordinates. This was introduced with QGIS 2.14 IMHO.

Comment: I've checked my Project Properties and the Coordinate display is set to Decimal degrees with precision Automatic.

Comment: I should add that this has happened on all my projects and those of my colleagues as well.

Comment: It's been a few years but I remember that Ordnance Survey data didn't used to come with projected coordinates, so make sure you set them for the layer

Comment: I've been using OS rasters with no problems for 5 years. It always showed my coordinates correctly. It has only been since I started using QGIS 2.14 that this problem has started. When I change the coordinates box to extents  it shows me these in the correct decimal format.